# Meaning of the Coulomb and Higgs branch for non-Lagrangian theories?

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry

What is the meaning of the Coulomb and Higgs branch for non-Lagrangian theories like the $T_N$ theories that arise as 5-brane webs and correspond to CY 3-folds in M-theory? This is related to an older question of Yuji Tach. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27267/on-the-coulomb-branch-of-n-2-supersymmetric-gauge-theory) but no answer was given.

Is there some basic overview-review of non-Lagrangian $\mathcal{N}=2$ theories that would clearly explain the basics?